# How do people share lists of RSS feeds?

Tags: rss

I have a list of about 30 RSS feeds I would like to share with the world. I don't expect my audience to all be opml experts or willing to take an opml file and import it into their rss reader of choice. I do expect them to be able to follow a link in browser, but not much more.

Bloglines, it seems used to have a sharing feature like this, but it seems to require me to send an email to each person in the world who might want to see my list. I'd rather anyone with a browser be able to see the list or better yet, the posts represented by the feeds.

There used to be a service called share.opml.org which appears to redirect to an unreleated entity now. That would have answered my question if they hadn't shut down.

Comment: If you have some hosting company for a private website/webpage with a minimum of available technologies for you to use, you can easily setup a webpage yourself that will show all the feeds you want. Probably some ready-made modules out there if you don't want to have to write this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the RSS feed setup in Google Reader all you need to do to share your feeds (in one quick swoop) is on your main RSS page >> under People you follow >> click Sharing Settings >> under Increase your Reader audience click on the link "Email them a link" or you'll see you have a unique URL where you can make your feeds public and anybody can access them.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not intended as this you can create an account at [FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com/) and add the RSS feeds you want to show (use the `Custom RSS/Atom` option). It's very unlikely but they might delete your account for using it in an non-intended manner (it should aggregate your own blog postings and not the ones of others).